# Translating DGN geometry to Esri File Geodatabase using FME?

Tags: geometry, file-geodatabase, fme-form, dgn

I am trying to import geometry in dgn file to a point feature class in arcgis file geodatabase. I have a layer in dgn file 'baum' which bascially means trees. I want to store these features in CAD drawing to the corresponding point feature class in fgdb. Moreover there are two kinds of tree. so i have used the joiner filter. that works well.

now since dgn file have multiple geometry in one layer i should use geometry filter. this translates all 4741 features but the inspector doesnot show it. I am new to FME so please guide me.

below are some screenshots which could be helpful to correct me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you loading in the .cel file? http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/FAQ/Microstation-Design-Cells-and-FME

Comment: my reader is a dgn file. i am writing into esri fgdb.

Comment: the .dgn file which i am reading has a layer with several geomerty types (igds_point, igds_line, igds_arc, igds_arc) which is  usual. Now the feature class in fgdb is point feature. So i guess the problem is, point feature in fgdb could not handle geometry types, arc and ellipse. what filter i need to use to get this working?

Comment: Convert your DGN to a DXF and then use the tool convert CAD to Vector.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I see the point of filtering all of your geometries and writing them to a feature class.  It's true that a Microstation cell is (or can be) made up of multiple geometry types.  However, Microstation sees them as one object.  If you filter all of your geometries and write them all to points, you're going to end up with duplicates.

A better option would be to write each cell as a point feature.  Have a look through the documentation on [**Cells**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Desktop_Help.htm#../Subsystems/FME_Readers_Writers/Content/igds/Cells.htm%3FTocPath%3DFME%2520Readers%2520and%2520Writers%7CBentley%2520MicroStation%2520Design%2520Reader%252FWriter%7CFeature%2520Representation%7CCells%7C_____0) and figure out what case you have.  Cells can be very complex.  In any case, there will be an insertion point for the cells.  I would use this as the coordinates for your points.  From your screenshot, I can see that you have the following attributes:

```
igds_cell_insertion_x
igds_cell_insertion_y
igds_cell_insertion_z
```

You can use these coordinates to create point representations of your cells.  Using a **[VertexCreator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2015.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Desktop_Help.htm#cshid=fmx_VertexCreator)** transformer, set the Mode to "Replace with Point" and the X, Y, and Z values will be the above attributes. Your output will be points with all of the other attributes of your cells.